# Scheduling Tasks in Angular 5

Tags: angular, typescript, fullcalendar, angular-cli, angular5

### How to insert an event calendar in Angular 5 ?

After much research I found [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/), but I got many problems in the implementation of my [Angular](https://angular.io/) project 5.

Does anyone know of something similar to [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) that works in [Angular CLI](https://cli.angular.io/)?

I would like to create a component that schedules tasks on certain dates, since since [FullCalendar](https://fullcalendar.io/) would be a great solution, I would like something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the best-supported one for Angular 5+ is the [angular-calendar](https://github.com/mattlewis92/angular-calendar). I haven't used it personally, but it is updated pretty-regularly (last release, as of this point in time, was 4 days ago). Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://themes.nyasha.me/#primer) is an example with Angular and Fullcalendar. It is a payed template ( no advertising or anything) I used it in order to understand how to use in Angular app.. On Themeforest you can find several alternatives